# Console logs format has changed in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

Suddenly the log format in run/debug tab of intelliJ has changed from default format to the json fromt as mentioned below. I am not sure how it got changed or how to revert it. It is hard to read/debug the code log from this format.

```
{"instant":{"epochSecond":1630330436,"nanoOfSecond":197120650},"thread":"main","level":"INFO","loggerName":"com.useargo.bi.dashboard.DashboardServiceApplication","message":"No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog","threadId":1,"threadPriority":5}
```

It is a spring boot application and i am using default SLF4J logger.

does any one how to revert it back to the default/original format?

Thanks.

Comment: What type of a java application is this? Are you using any logging libraries?

Comment: this is a spring boot application and i am using default SLF4J logger.

Answer (score 2):

It will be hard to tell what changed in your project. Check for any JSON/Logstash encoder that got added into your project recently, or any custom log configurations that was recently introduced.

For local dev and debug needs, I keep a gitignored copy of the following xml (`logback.xml`) in the project classpath, inside `src/main/resources`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="false">
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
  <property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN" value="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %X{id} %c{1} - %msg%n" />

  <appender name="CONSOLE_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
      <charset>utf8</charset>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE_APPENDER" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Here is the [documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html) which gives information on how patterns work.